# Generate a probability distribution from a histogram with two peaks in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a histogram with two peaks and I want to generate the corresponding probability distribution. I have used the following MATLAB code:

```
A=mydata;
M1=max(A);
M2=min(A);
I=(0:100).*(M1-M2)./100+M2;
[n,x]=hist(A,I);
bar(x,n/(1000*0.352))
```

I found this code frequently to explain how we can find a prob distribution for a histogram of random numbers normally distributed but I don't know whether if this true for a histogram with two peaks and generate a normalised probability distribution.

The histogram is shown here:

[image: The bimodal histogram]

Answer (score 2):

You can use an kernel density eestimation. In Matlab, the function name is [ksdensity](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/ksdensity.html). In R, the function name is density. The data used to generate the histogram are the same to generate the density.

Answer (score 2):

The following should help get you started

```
%% Generate some data
X1 = 10 + 5 * randn(200, 1);
X2 = 20 + 8* randn(250,1);
X = [X1; X2];

%% Fit a distribution using a kernel smoother
myFit = fitdist(X, 'kernel')

%% Visualize the resulting fit
index = linspace(min(X), max(X), 1000);
plot(index, pdf(myFit, index))

%% Generate a set of 500 random numbers drawn from the distribution
numbers = random(myFit, 500, 1);
numbers(1:10)

%% Inspect the complete set of methods for myFit
methods(myFit)
```